# Discussion board - Reply issue

Tags: discussion-board

I have a discussion board and have set an item level permission `Manage Hierarchy` depending upon the users. Means user can able to see the discussion in which that particular user have rights. My issue is I have a right in a discussion say "Disc1". But I am not able to reply in that discussion.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to select "**Create and Edit All Items**" option from *Create and Edit Access* section in the Discussion Board *Advanced Settings*.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a permission issue...It seems some custom code is written on Reply button which is preventing user from replying. More details will be required as he is able to submit reply for any other discussion topic or is it for just one topic. Is there any custom code written on the page?